# Selecting a value from an actionPerformed method

Tags: java, jcombobox

I'm trying to get the value from the variable `dificultad`, which is inside the `actionPerformed` method to use it in another class. But I really have no clue on how to do it. So I don't know if maybe you could help.

```
jComboBox1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            int dificultad;
            if (jComboBox1.getSelectedItem() == "Facil") {
                dificultad = 10;
                System.out.println("Facil");
            } else if (jComboBox1.getSelectedItem() == "Intermedio") {
                dificultad = 8;
                System.out.println("Intermedio");
            } else if (jComboBox1.getSelectedItem() == "Dificil") {
                dificultad = 4;
                System.out.println("Dificl");
            } else if (jComboBox1.getSelectedItem() == "Extremo") {
                dificultad = 1;
                System.out.println("Extremo");
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a variable (public) at the top of your class.

```
public class testClass {
    public int testVar = 0;

    public void action(){
        jComboBox1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            int dificultad;
            if (jComboBox1.getSelectedItem() == "Facil") {
                dificultad = 10;
                System.out.println("Facil");
            } else if (jComboBox1.getSelectedItem() == "Intermedio") {
                dificultad = 8;
                System.out.println("Intermedio");
            } else if (jComboBox1.getSelectedItem() == "Dificil") {
                dificultad = 4;
                System.out.println("Dificl");
            } else if (jComboBox1.getSelectedItem() == "Extremo") {
                dificultad = 1;
                System.out.println("Extremo");
            }
            testVar = dificultad;
        }
        }
    }
}
```

To use the value in an other class, simply pass the class object in - for example - a `main` function and access to the variable.

```
public class testClass2 {
    public testClass;

    public testClass2(testClass tc) {
        this.testClass = tc;
    }

    public void anotherAction(){
        if (this.testClass.testVar == 1) {
            System.out.println("Extremo!");
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
//set a field to use outside the scope of addActionListener()
int laDificulty = 0;

jComboBox1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            int dificultad;
            if (jComboBox1.getSelectedItem() == "Facil") {
                dificultad = 10;
                System.out.println("Facil");
            } else if (jComboBox1.getSelectedItem() == "Intermedio") {
                dificultad = 8;
                System.out.println("Intermedio");
            } else if (jComboBox1.getSelectedItem() == "Dificil") {
                dificultad = 4;
                System.out.println("Dificl");
            } else if (jComboBox1.getSelectedItem() == "Extremo") {
                dificultad = 1;
                System.out.println("Extremo");
            }
            laDificulty = dificultad;

        }
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but didnt work, asks to initialize it and to make it as a final variable, but after doing so, i still cant asign the value to the new variable... but thanks again...

Comment: could you paste more code? ex. the method that contains this addEvent()

Comment: actually its right, just that i forgot to make the variable public.. but thanks a lot... :)